# Ошибка типов. В чем причина? И print, как правильно оформить?

Tags: python, функции, типы-данных

```
from typing import List, Dict
work = ["In the sample standard deviation formula, for this example, the numerator is the sum of the squared deviation of each individual animal’s metabolic rate from the mean metabolic rate", "The table below shows the calculation of this sum of squared deviations for the female fulmars", "For females, the sum of squared deviations is 886047.09, as shown in the table"]
def uwork(work:List[str]) -> List[Dict[str]]:
    text = ' '.join(work) 
    text_dopol = text.replace(',','')
    return(list(sorted(set(text_dopol))))
print(uwork(work))
```

я в питоне совсем новичок, поэтому прошу объяснить подробно, насколько это возможно.

Answer (score 1):

Словарь требует указать два типа: тип ключа и тип значения. Вот так уже не ругается:

```
Dict[str,str]
```

Хотя где у вас в самом коде словарь? У вас только множество, список и т.д.
На выходе из функции у вас список строк (каждая строка состоит из одной буквы при этом).

Вам надо для начала разобраться: что вы вообще делаете и зачем, пока непонятно, зачем вы хотели использовать словарь и что вы хотите напечатать (поэтому вопрос про `print` непонятен - сначала напишите, что вы хотите получить).

Comment: мне нужно объединить все предложения в одно, отсортировать по алфавиту и вывели слова без повтора. Сначала я предложения соединяю с помощью .join, после убираю все запятые, получая лишь ряд слов. И далее их в return сортирую лишь на уникальные с помощью множества (set). forted их по алфавиту еще сортирует

Comment: и я действительно спутала тип.Мы пишем List[Set[str]]?

Comment: Вы `set` применяете к полученной строке со словами целиком, получая в результате уникальный набор **букв**. Чтобы получить уникальный набор **слов** надо разбить строку на слова: `set(text_dopol.split())` Ну и на выходе из функции у вас конечно `List[str]`, а `set` используется только как промежуточный этап.